# Is there a way to query Visualforce pages that have "Require CSRF protection on GET requests" set to false?

Tags: visualforce, soql

I'm working with an org that has hundreds of Visualforce pages, I've been manually checking this setting so far. Is there a better time-saving way to query visualforce pages that have this setting set to false?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is. Open your Developer Console and select the Query Editor tab. Check the box labeled "Use Tooling API". Then run the following query:

```
SELECT FullName From ApexPage WHERE IsConfirmationTokenRequired = false
```

You'll get back the API names (with namespace prefix) of all your pages where that setting is not enabled. Ask for the `MasterLabel` or `Name` columns instead to get back the page's human-readable name or API name without namespace.

For more, see the Tooling API reference for the [ApexPage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexpage.htm) entity.